# Parsing Youtube Annotations XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, youtube, annotations

While parsing XML with php is not exactly a new topic, I have had problems ensuring I parse Annotations from Youtube due to the varying information coming back.

I have spent quite a lot of time reading up about iterating over the attributes (which I think would be the "safe way") but, unfortunately, I have been unsuccessful with my attempts.

**Iterating:**

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/annotations_invideo?video_id=GUmcQuJVCrI");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
$role = $child->attributes();

foreach($child as $key => $value) {
    if($role == "annotation")
    echo "Role:".$role. "<br />";
    echo("[".$key ."] ".$value . "<br />");
}



}
```

Another way I have tried to parse the information is by actually following the paths of the nested elements for example:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/annotations_invideo?video_id=tFYaQwYbvxg");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$xml = $xml->annotations[0];
```

Then with a foreach loop:

```
foreach($xml->annotation as $annotation) {
```

I have been able to retrieve some of the information I require

```
$startX = ($annotation->segment->movingRegion->rectRegion[0]->attributes()->x[0]);
$endX = ($annotation->segment->movingRegion->rectRegion[1]->attributes()->x[0]);

$startY = ($annotation->segment->movingRegion->rectRegion[0]->attributes()->y[0]);
$endY = ($annotation->segment->movingRegion->rectRegion[1]->attributes()->y[0]);

$startW = ($annotation->segment->movingRegion->rectRegion[0]->attributes()->w[0]);
$endW = ($annotation->segment->movingRegion->rectRegion[1]->attributes()->w[0]);

$startH = ($annotation->segment->movingRegion->rectRegion[0]->attributes()->h[0]);
$endH = ($annotation->segment->movingRegion->rectRegion[1]->attributes()->h[0]);

$startT = ($annotation->segment->movingRegion->rectRegion[0]->attributes()->t[0]);
$endT = ($annotation->segment->movingRegion->rectRegion[1]->attributes()->t[0]);
```

I am well aware this is very messy and it fails if the data is anyway different or if there is an annotation type that I didnt know about.

I have been able to stop it failing for example type "text" annotations by ignoring some annotation types like so...

```
$type = $annotation->attributes()->type;
if (($type !="promotion") &&($type !="branding") &&($type !="card")&&($type !="drawer"))
```

but this is not really what I want to do in the long run, i really need to be able to parse all types even if Youtube had a new type tomorrow!

**Summary:**

I really need a safe, reliable way to be able to retrieve all annotations from any Youtube video and store all the information about each one such as the position X and Y, the start time and end time, the text if exists, the link if exists.

I also need the styling if exists.

If exists is the main problem here I think!

I have it working well for some annotations but not all....

I would appreciate if someone could advise me how to better format this so it is reliable and efficient.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Comon  Anybody, please?